# Error:No resource found that matches the given name (at 'minHeight' with value '?attr/actionBarSize')

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to build android studio project, and I'm getting following errors:

```
Error:(11, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'minHeight' with value '?attr/actionBarSize').
Error:(12, 29) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '?attr/colorPrimary').
```

below is my **XML FILE** : -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:qwerjk="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/builder_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layout_bottom"
    android:layout_below="@id/builder_toolbar"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/lCanvas"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgEditor"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <qwerjk.better_text.MagicTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEditTop"
            style="@style/BuilderText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/imgEditor"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="TOP"
            qwerjk:strokeColor="#FF000000"
            qwerjk:strokeJoinStyle="miter"
            qwerjk:strokeWidth="5" />

        <qwerjk.better_text.MagicTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEditMid"
            style="@style/BuilderText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="MID"
            qwerjk:strokeColor="#FF000000"
            qwerjk:strokeJoinStyle="miter"
            qwerjk:strokeWidth="5" />

        <qwerjk.better_text.MagicTextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEditBot"
            style="@style/BuilderText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgEditor"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="BOTTOM"
            qwerjk:strokeColor="#FF000000"
            qwerjk:strokeJoinStyle="miter"
            qwerjk:strokeWidth="5" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/lCanvas"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/lCanvas" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEditTop"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:text="@string/top" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEditMid"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:text="@string/center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEditBot"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_blue"
            android:text="@string/bottom" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_bottom"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSave"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_submit"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:id="@+id/submitText"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp" />


    </FrameLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>

<include layout="@layout/loading_overlay"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my **gradle.properties** file contains this :-

```
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=23.0.0
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=23
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=14
```

my **build.gradle** file :-

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION)
    buildToolsVersion project.ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION)
    targetSdkVersion Integer.parseInt(project.ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION)
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
publishNonDefault true

productFlavors {
    cheezburger {

    }
    loquillo{
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
provided 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
provided 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
provided 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
 }
```

any issues in this configuration ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your attrs.xml file locaked in values folder.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani I'm using attributes from currently applied theme. and i.e what ? in android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" indicates. correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: have you tried passing in the concrete values for sdk versions instead of using Integer wrapper?

Comment: @PuruPawar Yes I did but the issue still persist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned above there are two attributes which are causing an issue :-

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

I've replaced this by following line and it worked

```
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

For second one i.e  `android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"` I tried by `android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"` but it is compatible with android lollipop and above.

So I've to assign background with my custom color code / drawable like `android:background = "#FF00FF"` and with no doubt this works perfectly.

If any body has solution other than this please do let me know.